# How to check empty text box in form with client side validation and iterate Text boxes in form?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to iterate over all of the text inputs in the form and check if any of them are empty as a part of the validation.

How do I do that in pure JavaScript? I haven't got any -useful- piece of code for the situation as I was unfamiliar with doing it without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use Client Side validation by jquery or javascript.

For Reference -

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/10/javascript-user-registration-form-validation-source-code.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/404274/Client-Side-Validation-using-JavaScript

Comment: You showed an example for each textbox, not an example of how to iterate over every textbox.